# The act of declaring and revoking a structure a church

Tags: word-request, terminology

What is it called when a building is announced to be a church, like, *effective now, tada, this is a church*?

And conversely, what is it called when a church is revoked the rights of such, as in *it looks like it's been a church but is used like a museum*?

I rejected *churchify/dechurchify* because it's not listed in Webster. I rejected *canonize/excommunicate* because those seem to refer a person.

Comment: "Churchify" is a word in British English (since the 18th century) but it has the wrong meaning - it also applies to people, not to buildings. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/churchify

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I can only speak for the Catholic Church. My next door neighbor is a Catholic priest and according to him:

A church is *commissioned*/*decommissioned*. The same term as used for many other types of buildings when they are taken in use for a particular purpose.

The act of commissioning a church requires the church to be made "Holy Ground". This involves a number of church rituals and is called the "Consecration" of the church. *Consecrate*/*consecration* can also be used as a verb and noun, and is often done so as an alternative to commissioning/commission, but it is not quite the same thing. An unused church which is still Holy Ground can be re-commissioned without the need for a Consecration.

In order to decommission a church, it is not really required to de-consecrate it.  It is sufficient to stop using it as a church, but it will remain Holy Ground, until something takes place that de-sanctifies the place. (E.g. a serious act of desecration. Minor vandalism, like kicking over a tombstone in a graveyard, isn't enough. Having sex on the altar would do it. This actually happened in 2017 in a church in The Netherlands.)
There is also a church procedure to remove the Holy Ground status if desired. This is typically done if it is known in advance the place is going to be re-used for a purpose that is clearly at odds with its former usage as Holy Ground.

If a church is *de-sanctified* (lost its Holy Ground status) it needs to be re-consecrated before it can be used as a church again.
This is more involved than the regular consecration ritual as it consists of 2 parts: Removing the "evil" stain that de-sanctified it (making it neutral ground again) and then the normal consecration procedure.

P.S. Same thing applies to chapels and graveyards.

Answer (score 31):

A place can be **consecrated** as a church and later **deconsecrated**.

Comment: I've never heard "deconsecrated" - got a citation? It would certainly make sense in context, I'm just wondering if it's the most-common word for that (or if there even is a word).

Comment: "Deconsecrated" is a word. "Deconsecrate" is the verb with the opposite meaning to "consecrate". https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/deconsecrate. Note, "deconsecrated" does *not* have the same meaning as "unconsecrated," which is always an adjective - there is no verb "to unconsecrate": https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unconsecrated.

Comment: Pls consider editing alephzero's comment into the answer. Alternatively, @alephzero post this comment as your own answer. (Answers should be backed up with evidence like this)

Comment: Couldn’t desecrate also be used https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/desecrate? It seems to just be a shortened version, and while it may not be a precise antonym, it still implies that a place is made less sacred. It’s also more familiar to my Am Eng ear, but I can’t speak to Brit Eng.

Comment: @Imperator: No, **desecrate** means to treat the consecrated with disrespect, like spray-painting a gravestone, or tossing ritual vessels onto the floor. Desecration is vandalism or similar.  It does not mean to desanctify a place in a ritual manner that shows respect for its once "holy" status.

Comment: @Imperator No. Desecration is the violation of the holy status of a place; deconsecration is the removal of the holy status by the church, so the place can be used for something else.